# Python Testing a CLI application with required arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, testing

First off: I am quite new to the field of testing. So there might be some things wrong in my understanding.

My situation is the following: I'm working on a framework-ish where the end-user has to inherit from a parent class I've predefined. They're required to override four abstract methods I've defined in the parent class, and write there magic code inside of these methods.

The framework offers three different modes to run in. Because I want to ensure no mistakes are being made I've added a positional CLI argument to set that mode.

Here is my problem: I'm trying to write a unittest for every module in my application. Because the parent class mentioned above has quite some code, I'd like to unittest this as well.

Needless to say, it will not run without providing the required positional argument.

I've looked around to see how I can provide this argument programmatically, but the internet tells me that a unittest should be able to run without any outside information (makes sense).

My question: How do I test such a module? Are there other types of tests that are suited for these kinds of problems?

Thank you in advance!

### UPDATE

Here is a code example as requested in the comments. The actual mode variable is passed around a few other classes I've kept out of this example to keep it short. But the problem here is that if you run `python user.py` (which in my case PyCharm does for me when running the unittest) it requires the mode argument to be set. Unit testing the BaseClass also won't work, since the abstract methods are not overridden.

```py
from abc import abstractmethod
from abc import ABC
import argparse

# base.py
class BaseClass(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        self.args = self._parse_cli_args()

    def _parse_cli_args(self):
        self.parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
            description='MyApp'
        )

        self.parser.add_argument(
            'mode',
            choices=[
                'mode1',
                'mode2',
                'mode3'
            ],
            metavar='MODE [mode1, mode2, mode3]'
        )

    # the methods i'd like to unittest
    def methodIWantToTest1(self):
        # some useful computations
        pass

    def methodIWantToTest2(self):
        # some useful computations
        pass

    def methodIWantToTest3(self):
        # some useful computations
        pass


    # methods that should be overridden by end User (UserClass below)
    @abstractmethod
    def abstractMethod1(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def abstractMethod2(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def abstractMethod3(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def abstractMethod4(self):
        pass

# user.py
class UserClass(BaseClass):
    def AbstractMethod4(self):
        super().abstractMethod4()
    #     users implementation here

    def AbstractMethod3(self):
        super().abstractMethod3()
    #     users implementation here

    def AbstractMethod2(self):
        super().abstractMethod2()
    #     users implementation here

    def AbstractMethod1(self):
        super().abstractMethod1()
        # users implementation here
```

Comment: You need to post some code with a specific problem and an MVCE. This is too broad as written.

Comment: So you're talking about different things here ... An abstract base class that things need to inherit from and CLI parameters.  It'd be really helpful to see a (stripped down) example of how the CLI parameter data gets passed to the methods in the class.

Comment: I think you want to set `sys.argv`

Comment: I've updated the question with an extremely stripped down, but accurate version of my code. Thank you all for your response.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini I have tried using `sys.argv` but since I'm seeing very mixed opinions of using it in a unittest I'm wondering if there isn't a better solution.

Comment: I don't understand how your sample code relates to command line arguments. How is your question different than "How do I test methods implemented in an abstract class?" Do you have two separate questions?